# Why won’t my pseudo-selector code work?

Tags: html, css

My pseudo-selector code isn’t working even though it has worked before. I’m not sure why. Can some one help me figure out what’s wrong?

#### HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link style="styleheet" href=-"style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="HomepageHTML.html">Home</a><br>
        <a href="whykidscodehtml.html">Why should kids code?</a>
    </body> 
</html>
```

#### CSS:

```css
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #df808f;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: Is it working..a tag getting their color change on hover..what else you need.

Comment: What is the problem ? https://jsfiddle.net/L8e0Lku3/

Comment: @Hearner i made the same fiddle and asked same question from op but he is not replying.. I think its spam on site.

Comment: `href=-"style.css"` should be `href="style.css"`, and such typos are [off-topic (#2)](/help/on-topic) as they are of no further use to anyone after being fixed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the linking is causing the problem, as said in the comments, it works fine on fiddle.

Change this line:

```
<link style="styleheet" href=-"style.css">
```

into:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

The little minus after "href=..." is what broke it.